# Is it possible to run two Python files simultaneously in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, server, client, sublimetext3

I am trying to create a file sharing program using Python and to do that I am using a server. In order to test the program I need to use a different Python IDE to run the server and then use Sublime Text 3 to run the client. If possible, I would like to know if and how I can run both programs simultaneously in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

I feel it may just be best to run the python files via the terminal or command prompt. This would also in general be a better practice to run your programs. To run them, you would just need to type in... "python path/to/your/python/file"

Answer (score 0):

Each window gets its own build process. You can open both files in separate windows, run the build on the server, then run the build on client and they will both run simultaneously.